# Are number of cards in hand public knowledge?

Tags: cosmic-encounter

Are the number of cards in a players hand public knowledge? If a player requests to know the hand size of another player, does that player need to reveal the number of cards they have?

Comment: I've never heard this question asked before and I play games with a guy who will ask it if ever it might matter.  From my perspective I can't see any reason in this game for this question to be relevant.  The question as asked is good, but can you describe the situation where this question arose?

Comment: @LeppyR64 A player with more cards in hand is perhaps more likely to have a greater and stronger array of options at their command, so it is reasonable to incorporate this into strategic decisions like how big of an attack card to play. In other words, it's relevant _every single turn_, in addition to the specific alien powers etc that SocioMatt references in his answer.

Comment: @LeppyR64 This question came up because the Genius was one of the alien powers in play. The Genius wins if they have 20 cards in their hand. In our case, we wanted to know how close the person playing the Genius was to winning, and base our decisions accordingly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**While there's no specific rule governing this in the rulebook, the board gaming community as a whole seems to agree that the number of cards in a player's hand is public knowledge.**

There are a lot of forum threads that reiterate this answer on both BGG and Fantasy Flight Games ([here](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/1523727/misc-questions-regarding-last-playthrough), [here](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/1542106/does-genius-have-be-honest-about-number-cards-hesh), and [here](https://community.fantasyflightgames.com/topic/39640-how-many-cards-in-hand-and-a-question-about-zapping/?hl=hand), for starters). The basic reasoning for this is because some alien powers require that information to be public, such as the Mutant and the Genius. (And, if I remember correctly, one of the alternative win conditions for one of the alien races is to have more cards than the other players.)

Additionally, in the last link above, forum member Adam notes that the online game allows you to check the number of cards in a player's hand, although I haven't played it so I can't confirm whether that's true.

Comment: I'd say the same should be true of basically _every_ game involving cards (unless the rules explicitly say otherwise). Assuming players can see you draw the cards, there's not much point in giving you an incentive to hold your cards under the table and everyone else an incentive to keep running tallies while you draw and play.

Comment: (Also, I use the "if the rules aren't clear, use the most similar rule from MtG" standard :) )